# How to solve python Celery error when using chain EncodeError(RuntimeError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object))

Tags: python, celery

How do you run a chain task in a for loop since the signatures are generated dynamically. The following approach was used because defining the tester task as:

```
@task
def tester(items):
    ch = []
    for i in items:
        ch.append(test.si(i))
    return chain(ch)()
```

would raise an error of  `EncodeError(RuntimeError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object',),)` if the chains are too large which is os or system specific.

> E.g calling the task as follows

```
item = range(1,40000) #40,000 raises exception but #3,000 doesn't after setting sys.setrecursionlimit(15000)
tester.delay(item)
```

raises the `EcodeError`. In the past I used to have this error when length of item is 5000 i.e range(1,5000). Which i fixed by importing `sys` and calling `sys.setrecursionlimit(15000)` at the top of the `module`. But there is a limitation to this so I decided to refactor a little and use the approach below. That is trying, to split the list and do it in chunks after chunks.The problem is it doesn't seem to continue after 2000 i.e test prints 2000 to screen.

```
@task
def test(i):
    print i


@task
def tester(items):
    ch = []
    for i in items:
        ch.append(test.si(i))
    counter = 1
    if len(ch) > 2000:
        ch_length = len(ch) #4k
        while ch_length >= 2000:
            do = ch[0:2000] # 2k
            print "Doing...NO#...{}".format(counter)
            ret = chain(do)() #doing 2k
            print "Ending...NO#...{}".format(counter)
            ch = ch[2000:] #take all left i.e 2k

            ch_length = len(ch) #2k
            if ch_length <= 2000 and ch_length > 0:
                print "DOING LAST {}".format(counter)
                ret = chain(ch)()
                print "ENDING LAST {}".format(counter)
                break
            else:
                break
            counter +=1
    else:
        ret = chain(ch)()
    return ret
```

According to celery documentation, a chain basically executes task within it one after the other. I expect the while loop to continue only first iteration is conpleted in the chain before proceeding.

I hope someone has experience with this and could help.

Merry Xmas in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you met this issue: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1078

Also calling `chain(ch)()` seems to execute it asynchronously. Try to explicitely call `apply()` on it.

```
@app.task
def tester(items):
    ch = []
    for i in items:
        ch.append(test.si(i))

    PSIZE = 1000
    for cl in range(0, len(ch), PSIZE):
        print("cl: %s" % cl)
        chain(ch[cl:cl + PSIZE]).apply()
        print("cl: %s END" % cl)
    return None
```

Comment: Bravo! This seems to be working with the actual test snippet I provided. Would see whats going to happen with actual code and revert. Thanks this is a head start especially with the `apply()`

Comment: I'd like to say that calling `chain([t, t, t, ...]).apply()` in a loop is the same as calling `t()` in a loop. I mean celery is not needed in this case.

Comment: you are right but the reason i use this approach is that in my actual code, test() performs calls other tasks and also does some CRUD in database. Well regardless i think without the chain it would work